# Mobile Home Parks

Tags: usa, data.gov, real-estate

I would like to create a list of all mobile home parks in the US, including address, owner records, and number of pads.  How can I find a list of all mobile home parks by State and sorted by number of pads?

Comment: Openstreetmap may have a relevant tag, but is likely incomplete.

Comment: @gerrit seems it's proposed but not yet in use https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/Trailer_Park

Comment: @philshem Proposed ten years ago, oh well.  Seems like they need a better issue tracking and decision taking system as well!

Answer (score 1):

Not the solution you seek, but this list should get you started.
There are a few national datasets, but considering the logistics of collecting it all, and how there are many more state/local datasets, you may find more success/more accurate datasets on those levels.
[Mobile Home Parks - Homeland Infrastructure Foundation-Level Data (HIFLD)](https://hifld-geoplatform.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/mobile-home-parks/data)
[HIFLD Mobile Home Parks GeoJSON](https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/4cdbccc5c538452aa91ceee277c460f9_0.geojson)
[Oregon Manufactured Dwelling Park Directory and Query](http://o.hcs.state.or.us/MDPCRParks/ParkDirQuery.jsp?txtQueryType=County&txtStatusQuery=Open&mnuCounty=18Klamath)
[Oregon Manufactured Home Park Directory](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=04e0c77d18cb456a9ecef78900c73748)
[Search ESRI ArcGIS for tags:"Mobile Homes"](https://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=tags%3A%22Mobile%20Homes%22)
[Search ESRI ArcGIS for tags:"single family detached"](https://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=tags%3A%22single%20family%20detached%22)
[Search ESRI ArcGIS for tags:"housing units"](https://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=tags%3A%22housing%20units%22)
[Search ESRI ArcGIS for tags:"Mobile Home Park"](https://www.arcgis.com/home/search.html?q=tags%3A%22Mobile%20Home%20Park%22)
Zillow has tons of [neighborhood data](https://www.zillowgroup.com/developers/public-data/); you can also do a search for "Mobile" by state: [Here's Florida's Results](https://www.zillow.com/fl/mobile/).
[Mobile Homes in the City of Dallas](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=bfb137bbbcef420daa2605f3526313e9)
[Mobile Home (Miami-Date County)](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fd04712e60104c13bf28a3432b235e78)
[Housing Units In Structure by Tract, 2012-2016](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1099341c1a0a4ecd953a6f442c77f627) is an ACS dataset.
[ACS - American Community Survey](https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/) has a bunch of related datasets.